# Convert date stored variable into unix time BASH

Tags: bash, unix, time

I'm trying to convert a date stored in a variable into unix timestamp. I have the value, I must provide the format of this value("%m%d%Y") and then convert it ("%s"). Could you please give me a hint?

```
>initial_date=02012014
>date_2_unixtime=`date +"%m%d%Y" -d $initial_date +"%s"`
date: extra operand `+%s'
Try `date --help' for more information.
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your date is in `mmddyyyy`, it needs to be in `yyymmdd` for `date` to interpret. Also you don't provide input date format to date command. Format is for display purpose only.

Use it this way:

```
initial_date=02012014
dt="${initial_date:4}${initial_date:0:4}"
date +"%s" -d "$dt"
1391230800
```

Comment: what I am curious is, why your output is `1391230800` instead of `1391209200`?

Comment: @Kent: Timezone offset :) My clock was set for EDT which is 6 hrs behind UTC.

Comment: @Kent, I guess anubhava comes from the future :)

Comment: @anubhava thank you. I thought `%s` is a diff, after 1970-01-01. so it would be TZ independent. but after reading the man page and testing a bit, I am wrong. the 1970-01-01 is a UTC TS. but when doing the `%s`,  it using the `date` in current timezone. Never thought about it before.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is, you have to convert your initial_date into a format that `date` recognize.

`02012014` is not one of them, unfortunately.

```
kent$  date -d "02012014"
date: invalid date ‘02012014’
```

if you prefer an one-liner, you could try:

```
date -d $(sed -r 's#(..)(..)(....)#\1/\2/\3#' <<<$initial_date) +%s
1391209200
```

Comment: do you mean `\3\2\1`?